# How to remove an unnecessary entry point in gulp setup with webpack-stream?

Tags: gulp, webpack

I'm new to webpack - been using gulp for a couple of years now.  Combining the two is a great learning experience because it's exposing some things I took for granted before.  Like below, I have a webpack.config.js that has an multiple entry points and an output.  I got this config from the [webpack-stream](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream) documentation, and it all makes sense to me except one part:
Gulp also has an entry point, called entry.js.  I couldn't think of another way to do it so I created a blank file named entry.js and just stuck a console.log in there.

```
gulp.task('webpack', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/script/entry.js')
        .pipe(webpack( require('./webpack.config.js') ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Running `gulp webpack` does exactly what I expect it to except my console statement disappears.  What's the purpose of entry.js?  Why does it seem to evaporate?  Is there a way to just not begin my task with `gulp.src()`?  I think I'm missing something when it comes to how pipes work.